# What is the structure of N₅P₃?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, molecules, solid-state-chemistry, pnictogen

What is the structure of the molecule $\ce{N5P3}$? $\ce{N5P3}$ is not documented online, so could anyone please comment on the structure of the molecule:

- How many ligands does each phosphorous atom have?
- How many ligands does each nitrogen atom have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why [previous answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/5983/41328) cited only the first paper on phosphorus(V) nitride $\ce{P3N5}$. A couple of years later the same team reported three polymorphs $\ce{α,β,γ-P3N5}$ with three-dimensional network. For $\ce{α-P3N5}$ and $\ce{γ-P3N5}$ crystal structures have been refined. Both modifications demonstrate vastly different structural types and coordination of pnictogens.

#### Low-pressure phase $\ce{α-P3N5}$

Data obtained via powder neutron diffraction with higher resolution by using synchrotron radiation. The crystal structure was determined by direct methods and refined by the Rietveld method. [1, 2]

Structure description from [1]:

> In $\ce{α-P3N5}$ zweier single chains occur parallel to $[110]$ and 
>   $[1\bar{1}0]$, in which the $\ce{PN4}$ tetrahedra are connected alternately through edge- and corner-sharing. These zweier single chains are linked together through additional vertex-sharing $\ce{PN4}$ tetrahedra. [...]  The network structure of connected $\ce{PN4}$ tetrahedra in $\ce{α-P3N5}$ could be characterized by analogy to condensed silicates by the specific distribution of the occurring $\ce{P_nN_n}$ ring sizes.

Liebau formula: $_\infty^3\ce{[P_3^{[4]} N_3^{[2]} N_2^{[3]}]}$ *

[image: Crystal structure of α-P3N5]

**Figure 1.** Crystal structure of $\ce{α-P3N5}$, view along $[010]$. Purple coordination tetrahedra correspond to $\ce{[PN4]}$.

#### Low-pressure phase $\ce{β-P3N5}$

$\ce{β-P3N5}$ was reported in a polymorphic mixture with $\ce{α-P3N5}$ and is it's stacking modification (no further crystallographic investigation has been published) [1]:

> On the basis of the solved crystal structure of $\ce{α-P3N5}$, we are now working on the determination of structural models for $\ce{β-P3N5}$, and disordered $\ce{P3N5}$. The HRTEM results show that similar to the situation in the polytypes of the different 
>   stacking variants are based on the same structural modules, which are linked in different ways.

#### High-pressure phase $\ce{γ-P3N5}$

Data obtained via powder X-ray diffraction. The crystal structure of $\ce{γ-P3N5}$ was determined by direct methods and refined using the Rietveld method. [3]

Structure description from [3]:

> The novel high-pressure modification consists of a polymeric three-
>   dimensional network structure of linked $\ce{PN4}$ tetrahedra and
>   tetragonal-pyramidal $\ce{PN5}$ units. [...] Rods from trans-edge-sharing $\ce{PN5}$ units running along $[010]$ are linked by vertices, leading to the formation of layers perpendicular to $[100]$. [...]  In accordance with the pressure–coordination rule a partial increase of the coordination number of the phosphorus atoms from four in $\ce{α-P3N5}$ to five in $\ce{γ-P3N5}$ is observed. [...] The density of $\ce{γ-P3N5}$ is $32\%$ higher than the density of $\ce{α-P3N5}$. [...] Therefore the high-pressure phase could show interesting materials properties (e.g. great hardness or low compressibility).

Liebau formula: $\ce{P_5^{[5]}[ P^{[4]} N_3]N_2}$ *

[image: Crystal structure of γ-P3N5]

**Figure 2.** Crystal structure of $\ce{γ-P3N5}$, view along $[010]$. Purple coordination tetrahedra correspond to $\ce{[PN4]}$; yellow coordination pyramids — to $\ce{[PN5]}$.

* using Liebau's nomenclature for silicates, where the superscripted number in square brackets after the element symbol denotes the coordination number.

#### References

1. Horstmann, S.; Irran, E.; Schnick, W. Synthesis and Crystal Structure of Phosphorus(V) Nitride α-P3N5. *Angewandte Chemie International Edition in English* **1997**, 36 (17), 1873–1875. https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.199718731.
2. Horstmann, S.; Irran, E.; Schnick, W. Phosphor(V)-nitrid $\ce{α-P3N5}$: Synthese ausgehend von Tetraaminophosphoniumiodid und Kristallstrukturaufklärung mittels Synchrotron-Pulver-Röntgenbeugung. *Zeitschrift für anorganische und allgemeine Chemie* **1998**, 624 (4), 620–628. https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1521-3749(199804)624:4<620::AID-ZAAC620>3.0.CO;2-K.
3. Landskron, K.; Huppertz, H.; Senker, J.; Schnick, W. High-Pressure Synthesis of $\ce{γ-P3N5}$ at 11 GPa and 1500 °C in a Multianvil Assembly: A Binary Phosphorus(V) Nitride with a Three-Dimensional Network Structure from $\ce{PN4}$ Tetrahedra and Tetragonal $\ce{PN5}$ Pyramids. *Angewandte Chemie International Edition* **2001**, 40 (14), 2643–2645. https://doi.org/10.1002/1521-3773(20010716)40:14<2643::AID-ANIE2643>3.0.CO;2-T.

Answer (score 13):

$\ce{N5P3}$ is more commonly written as $\ce{P3N5}$, and known as **[triphosphorus pentanitride](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C12136913)**. It's a **crystalline solid** at ambient conditions and **not** a molecular compound. From the first publication that reported the pure compound and its structure [[1]](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cm950385y):

> In the solid a three-dimensional cross-linked network structure of corner sharing $\ce{PN4}$ tetrahedra has been identified with 2/5 of the nitrogen atoms bonded to three P atoms and 3/5 of the nitrogen atoms bonded to two P atoms.
>
> [image]
>
> Only the combination of spectroscopical and diffraction methods, especially electron microscopy for structural analysis, enables a detailed structural and crystallographic characterization of $\ce{P3N5}$ as no conventional single-crystal data for structure determination have been available for this compound.
>
> A representative for an unique binary structure type was found for the first time which combines a tetrahedral structure with the very rare molar ratio of 3:5 for the constituent elements.

#### References

1. Schnick, W.; Lücke, J.; Krumeich, F. *Chem. Mater.* **1996**, 8 (1), 281–286 DOI: [10.1021/cm950385y](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cm950385y).